# Removing user account Windows XP SP2

Tags: windows-xp

I have 2 user accounts on my Windows XP Pro SP2 PC, both are administrators. I need to totally delete one of the accounts, but can't find the option on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Computer Managment:

[image]

Right click on the account and select "Delete"

Comment: The same "Local Users and Groups" 'snap-in' can be accessed through `lusrmgr.msc`, in case you'll ever need to do this often.

Comment: If I remember correctly this not accessible on Windows XP Home Edition. Just a heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Control Panel** > **User Accounts**, click the account you want to delete and click **Delete the account**.

You can read more about it [here](http://uis.georgetown.edu/software/documentation/winxp/winxp.deleting.accounts.html), if you like.

Answer (score 0):

In WinXP, you can also do this from the **Control Panel > System** (aka My Computer > Properties).  On the Advanced tab is a User Profiles section; click Settings.  This is usually used to make copies of a profile, but also allows you to delete one, or change a profile from roaming to local.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line - `net user UserName /delete`